# Custom adapter for Ember Data does not work

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, adapter

I use this guide to create a custom adapter for Ember Data: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html

In my app.js I have the following:

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
    adapter: 'MyAdapter'
});
```

I created the adapter:

```
App.MyAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend({
    createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
        console.log('create');
    },

    deleteRecord: function(store, type, record) {
        console.log('delete');
    },

    find: function(store, type, id) {
        console.log('find');
    },

    findAll: function(store, type, sinceToken) {
        console.log('findAll');
    },

    findQuery: function(store, type, query) {
        console.log('findQuery');
    },

    updateRecord: function(store, type, record) {
        console.log('updateRecord');
    }
});
```

And I created a model:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr,
    body: DS.attr,
    author: DS.attr
});
```

Then in a route I have:

```
this.store.createRecord('post', {
    title: 'Rails is Omakase',
    body: 'Lorem ipsum',
    author: 'asd'
});

var post = this.store.find('post');
console.log(post);
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, as there are several errors in console output:

- `Assertion failed: Unable to find fixtures for model type App.Post`
- `Assertion failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not null`
- `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null`.

So my first guess is, that it can't find my custom adapter, as there is also no logging if the function gets called (`console.log('find')`...). Is the documentation even up to date? Is the string `MyAdapter` correct? Shouldn't it be like this:

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
    adapter: 'App.MyAdapter'
});
```

Nothing works. What have I done wrong?

One further question: Is there a good ember data adapter for web sockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This documentation points to ember-data `1.0.0-beta.6` version and seems incorrect. In the meantime a [fix was sent](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/0628a8f82ecd1c97f36b52805eab8b680244f695), but it is just avaliable on master branch.

You can follow the new documentation and update your code to use `App.ApplicationAdapter`:

```
var MyAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend({
  ...
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = MyAdapter;
```

Of course you will receive errors because the empty methods, but a `findAll` will be logged.